# Oracle select count(*) into n generates ORA-01401 inserted value too large for column

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

I have spent hours tracking down the source of this bug and am stumped.  I managed to determine that the below simple select statement was the problem (comment and not error.. so yes, it's the cause).  n was initially defined as a number, I tried integer as well for grins.

```
n integer;

    n := 1;
select count(*) into n 
from category
where (
      upper(ltrim(rtrim(category_long_name))) = upper(ltrim(rtrim(cat_long_name)))
        or
      upper(ltrim(rtrim(category_short_name))) = upper(ltrim(rtrim(cat_short_name)))
        or
      upper(ltrim(rtrim(category_description))) = upper(ltrim(rtrim(cat_descr)))
      )  
  and (settings_setting_id = sett_id) and (category_id <> cat_id);
```

When this code is executed, I get *ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column*. So the only "insert" is into the n value for a row count.  The actual value (used debugger) is 0.

I don't understand how this could be causing a problem.  I've seen this select count(*) into x code snippet in examples.  The procedure runs fine with this statement commented out.  The only time 'n' is used is in the next step where I raise and exception if it's > 0.  I've literally commented out the entire stored procedure, leaving only this statement, and it causes the error.

My research online indicates that count(*) returns an integer.

The category table has about 50 rows in it.

What am I missing?

This is category:
"CATEGORY_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
"VERSION_VERSION_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
"SETTINGS_SETTING_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "CATEGORY_LONG_NAME" CHAR(256 BYTE), 
    "CATEGORY_SHORT_NAME" CHAR(25 BYTE), 
    "CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    "CATEGORY_FORM_ID" CHAR(10 BYTE), 
    "CATEGORY_FORM_SYNONYM" CHAR(256 BYTE), 
    "CATEGORY_GUIDE_FOR_USE" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    "CATEGORY_COMMENTS" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    "CATEGORY_EFFECTIVE_DATE" DATE, 
    "CATEGORY_UNTIL_DATE" DATE, 
    "CATEGORY_CREATOR" CHAR(50 BYTE), 
    "CATEGORY_ADMIN_STATUS" CHAR(25 BYTE), 
    "CATEGORY_ADMIN_STATUS_DATE" DATE, 
    "CATEGORY_REGISTR_STATUS" CHAR(25 BYTE), 
    "CATEGORY_REGISTR_STATUS_DATE" DATE, 
    "CATEGORY_STATUS" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    "CATEGORY_STATUS_JUST" VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE), 
    "CATEGORY_TYPE" NUMBER

There was some other stuff around the code snippet I sent so I created a new stored procedure where I assigned the values that would be passed as parameters (the variables I set in the debugger).  I still get the ORA-01401 on the select count(*) into N line.
The issues goes away when I comment out the where clause.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1 
IS 
  CATEGORY_NAME_EXISTS Exception;
  WRONG_ACTION_PARAM Exception;
  WRONG_PARAM_SET Exception;
  NO_JUSTIFICATION Exception;
  VERSION_PERSISTENT Exception;
  CANNOT_APPROVE Exception;
  VERSION_SETTING_NEEDED Exception;
  n number :=1;
  msg1 nvarchar2(2000);
  curr_status nvarchar2(10);
  curr_persistent number;
  curr_sett_status nvarchar2(10);
  update_with_hierarchy nvarchar2(3);
  sql_txt nvarchar2(1000);  
  err_num number;
  err_msg varchar2(200);
  CAT_LONG_NAME nvarchar2(1000) := 'Administrative';
  CAT_SHORT_NAME nvarchar2(1000) := 'Administrative';
  CAT_DESCR nvarchar2(1000) := 'Admin form';
  SETT_ID number := 2;
  CAT_ID number := 13;
  categORy_long_name nvarchar2(1000);
  categORy_shORt_name nvarchar2(1000);
  categORy_description nvarchar2(1000);
  settings_setting_id number;
  categORy_id number;
BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO n 
    FROM categORy

    WHERE
    (
        UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(categORy_long_name))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(cat_long_name)))
        OR
        UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(categORy_shORt_name))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(cat_shORt_name)))
        OR
        UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(categORy_description))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(cat_descr)))
    )  
    AND (settings_setting_id = sett_id) and (categORy_id <> cat_id)

    ;
END;
```

Comment: If the type of `n` were somehow `varchar(1)` then you would get this error when trying to store a two digit number coming from the count.

Comment: Please give us the table structure for category.

Comment: Nope.. n is a number.  I tried making it an integer too since I read count(*) returns an integer.  Same problem.

Comment: If you remove the conditions from your select and keep just `SELECT COUNT(*) INTO n FROM categORy` do you still get the error?

Comment: You're on to something.  The error does not happen when I comment out the where clause and exec the procedure.  After the first time I noticed that not all the variables in the where clause where defined.  Much excitement - but then I declared them and still the problem when the where clause isn't commented.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE
    n number := 1;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO n 
    FROM categORy
    WHERE
    (
        UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(categORy_long_name))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(cat_long_name)))
        OR
        UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(categORy_shORt_name))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(cat_shORt_name)))
        OR
        UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(categORy_description))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(cat_descr)))
    )  
    AND (settings_setting_id = sett_id) and (categORy_id <> cat_id);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks.. but same problem.